# List all Index in a string that satisfies a certain string

Tags: python, string, filereader

I am trying to use python to read a text file and search a certain string in the file as below

```
with open("controlDict","r") as myfile:
    file=myfile.read()

IndexFirst=file.find('fields')
```

However, I found out that it only gives me the first index of 'fields' in the file but I need to find all the indexes where 'fields' appears on the line.

I did some research online and tried below

```
Index=[i for i, val in enumerate(file) if val=='fields']
```

but it does not work and returns an empty list.

I am not sure why, anyone has any suggestions?

Comment: Do you want a list of indexes where the word fields appears?

Comment: You could use a regexp and `re.findall()`

Answer (score 1):

Open the file, loop over every line and check if it contains 'fields' and if it does, print the line

```
with open("controlDict", "r") as myfile:
    for line in myfile.readlines():
        if 'fields' in line:
            print(line)
```

If you just need the index of the line you can use

```
with open("controlDict", "r") as myfile:
    for index, line in enumerate(myfile.readlines()):
        if 'fields' in line:
            print(index)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the exact index where the word fields occurs in the file you can do the following:

```
str = "fields"
indices = []
i = 0
while i >= 0:
  i = file.find(str,i)
  indices.append(i)
```

If you want the line index you can use AK47's answer.

Answer (score 0):

if you want the indexes of the words

```
def all_occurences(file, str):
    initial = 0
    while True:
        initial = file.find(str, initial)
        if initial == -1: return
        yield initial
        initial += len(str)

print(list(all_occurences(open("controlDict.txt").read(), "fields")))
```

you can use this code

Answer (score 0):

The `re` module and list comprehension could be used:

```
import re

with open('controlDict.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    file = myfile.read()

indices = [match.start() for match in re.finditer('fields', file)]
```